# Are Chromebook questions off topic. Where to ask

Tags: discussion

I know we can ask questions about PC's, netbooks, laptops etc. But a Chromebook is a netbook I guess? Or not?

Either way, can I assume they will be off topic here in regards to help with Chromebook software? For example, this question: [Google Play Music](https://superuser.com/questions/763344/songs-incorrectly-added-to-multiple-google-play-music-albums), is it on or off topic? If off topic, should it be migrated and if so where? To Android? Webapps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky. The chromebook itself is probably on topic. google play music has android, web and a upload client for windows.

In *this* case, he's asking about the google play music manager, which is a desktop app, for windows and entirely on topic.

If he wanted to know where to *edit* this information after the fact on the webpage, it would belong on webapps, and if it involved the android app, it belongs on android.se